# Very weird! My list returns ArgumentOutofRangeException when trying to add

Tags: c#, list, addition

I'm doing a list of tasks for the program to do, and so I started a List object.
This List is a List of another class, that has the information of what to do (task) depending on a type (integrer).
It's a Host vs Client talk that both of them have the class (a bit different, just my understanding of the types (client task type 0 != host task type 0)) and my Host list works perfectly, but the client doesn't.

My NetObjects List returns ArgumentOutOfRangeException when trying to add a class (of NetObject) (I'll leave examples of code down).
I don't know why is this a thing, since the List is supposed to be infinite and when you add there is no index or something (it says index must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection).

Here is the error:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException (System.ExceptionArgument argument, System.ExceptionResource resource) (at :0)
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException () (at :0)
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].get_Item (System.Int32 index) (at :0)
>   Networking.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Networking.cs:225)

It says something of get item that I don't know why, because I use (in the code) the task reference with the index (reading it) and it happens nothing but only when I want to add to the NetObject to the Objects class. 
I'll show the Host code because that works and the Client doesn't and I don't get why.

I tried to put the locking to make it better (so that there is no overriding), but hasn't done more than make it better from my point of view.

This is the part of the client in which makes the tasks (are in Unity), I used tasks because Unity won't let change in game things (position, spawn, etc) if it's not from the main thread (and I use threads to receive and send information (talking between Client and Host)).

```
for (int i = 0; i < PendingClient.Count; i++) {
            if (PendingClient[i].id > -1)
                lock (lockingClient) {
                    switch (PendingClient[i].type) {
                        case 0:
                            GameObject go = null;
                            if (GetObjectFromId(PendingClient[i].id, ref go)) {
                                go.transform.position = new Vector3(PendingClient[i].px,
                                PendingClient[i].py, PendingClient[i].pz);

                                go.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(PendingClient[i].rx,
                                PendingClient[i].ry, PendingClient[i].rz);
                            } else {
                                Objects.Add(new NetObject(PendingClient[i].id,
                                PendingClient[i].objectType, PendingClient[i].name,
                                PendingHost[i].prefabName,
                                Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/" +
                                PendingClient[i].prefabName) as GameObject,
                                new Vector3(PendingClient[i].px, PendingClient[i].py,
                                PendingClient[i].pz), Quaternion.Euler(PendingClient[i].rx,
                                PendingClient[i].ry, PendingClient[i].rz))));
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    PendingClient.RemoveAt(i);
                }
        }
```

The error appears right below the last else.

And the Host code that works:

```
for (int i = 0; i < PendingHost.Count; i++) {
            lock (lockingHost) {
                if (PendingHost[i].id > -1) {
                    switch (PendingHost[i].type) {
                        case 0: // Add Object
                            Objects.Add(new NetObject(PendingHost[i].id, PendingHost[i].objectType, PendingHost[i].name, PendingHost[i].prefabName, Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/" + PendingHost[i].prefabName) as GameObject, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity)));
                            break;
                        case 1: // Change Transform
                            GameObject go = null;
                            GetObjectFromId(PendingHost[i].id, ref go);
                            go.transform.position = new Vector3(PendingHost[i].px, PendingHost[i].py, PendingHost[i].pz);
                            go.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(PendingHost[i].rx, PendingHost[i].ry, PendingHost[i].rz);
                            break;
                    }
                    PendingHost.Remove(PendingHost[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm not an Informatic Engineer, but I tried to make the better code I could.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: My guess is that it is do do with removing from the list IN the loop, so when you get to i = 6 of a 10 element list it will blow with the error you are getting. Why not just clear the list after the loop? Just a thought.

Comment: If you need to remove an element from a list while looping over the list with a for then use the old trick to enumerate the elements starting from the end _for (int i = PendingHost.Count-1; i >= 0; i--) {_

Comment: ok, it might work!

Comment: The `i` not only runs out of the range, but you are skipping elements, as after removing, the next element will replace the removed element at `i`, but the for-statement still increments `i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call

`PendingClient.RemoveAt(i);`

inside

```
for (int i = 0; i < PendingClient.Count; i++) {
```

so `i` eventually goes out of range.

Aside: instead of doing `PendingClient[i]` a dozen times, do

`var current = PendingClient[i]` up front and then use `current`.

Comment: This is correct, waste of calls to PendingClient also.  Also reverse your loop as @Steve mentioned above.